# How post-increment operator works with user defined types?

Tags: c++

I have a difficulty on how this post-increment operator works for user-defined types: As I guess the Post-Increment operator `operator++(T _unused)` saves the original value first (into the expression) then increment the variable. e.g:

```
int x{5};
int y{x++};
```

So `x = 6` and `y = 5` and that's ok.

But here is an example of user-defined:

```
struct s{
    int x;
    s(int m_) : x(m_){}
    s operator++(int){ x++; return *this;}
};


int main(){

    s a(0);
    a.x = 7;
    cout << "a::x: " << a.x << endl;

    s b(a++);

    cout << "a::x: " << a.x << endl; // 8
    cout << "b::x: " << b.x << endl; // 8 ?!

    int t = 9;
    s c(t++);

    cout << "c::x: " << c.x << endl; // 9
    cout << "t: " << t << endl; // 10 ok

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above: `s b(a++)` will make the values of `a.x` and `b.x` `8`? I can't understand why?

Thank you guys for your help and time and efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How post-increment operator works with user defined types?

The way you write it, as it is mostly a regular method.

It is good practice to avoid surprise, and so mimic behaviour of built-in types is good.

To mimic built-in type as `int`, you might fix implementation to:

```
struct s
{
    int x;
    explicit s(int m_) : x(m_){}
    s& operator++(){ ++x; return *this;} // pre-increment
    s operator++(int){ auto res = *this; ++*this; return res;} // post-increment
};
```

Comment: I already see code of matrix iterator which uses pre-increment for row increment, and post-increment for column increment :/ (horrible).

Answer (score 3):

Change the operator to this:

```
s operator++(int){ 
   s t{x++};
   return t;
}
```

The problem is that you're defining the operator in a way that it modify `this` before returning and the return is a copy of `this` modified, what you need is create a new `s` with the value of `x` before modification and return that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get a post-increment just by adding `int` to the function signature: you have to actually implement it!

Your code:

```
s operator++(int){ x++; return *this;}
```

This looks just like a pre-increment to me. Although it'll be called when you write `someSObject++`, all it does is increment the object's own `x` then return a copy of the object.

Instead, I think you meant something like:

```
s operator++(int)
{
    S result{*this};
    ++(*this);
    return result;
}
```

Or, tailored to this specific class for brevity:

```
s operator++(int)
{
    return s{x++};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You typically provide two overloads for the increment operator in a class:

```
class C {
public:
    C& operator++();   // pre-increment
    C operator++(int); // post-increment
    int i;
};
```

The thing is, naming these "pre-increment" and "post-increment" describes **how they're called**, not what they do.

```
C c;
++c; // calls operator++()
c++; // calls operator++(int)
```

To implement the usual semantics of pre- and post-increment you have to write code that does the appropriate thing.

Pre-increment means incrementing the value, and returning the new value:

```
C& C::operator++() {
    ++i;
    return *this;
}
```

Post-increment means incrementing the value and returning the **old** value:

```
C C::operator++(int) {
    C res(*this);
    ++*this;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What should you expect from: `s operator++(int){ x++; return *this;}`?

You can see that x is incremented before the copy constructor constructs the temporary object. Remember returning by value invokes copy constructor. You should construct the temporary object before incrementing the variable.

In your case you can change it to look like:

```
s operator++(int){ 
    return s(x++);
}
```

AS you can see above the temporary object is constructed with `x`'s value then x is incremented.

Comment: That is not a named return value.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Do you mean NRV is achieved with non member functions?

Comment: Of course it is. But, no, I mean, that is not a named return value. For a start, it does not have a name...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So is it relevant to call it "RVO"?

Comment: Yes that would be better

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thank you. Could you send me a link on "Named Return Value"?

Comment: Does your C++ book not explain it? Not that it really needs to. When you add "named", you're saying that it has a name!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I've read an article on it: "it is called RVO" and if I declare a temporary object then return it then it is "Named return value": `void foo(){S obj; return obj;}` is it true?

Comment: Yes, return value optimisation is a language feature, and if applied to a thing with a name then it is _named_ return value optimisation. Please consider purchasing one of these books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thank you. I've already have purchased many of them.